# How to login to site _only_ from my webbrowser control?

Tags: .net, browser, c#-2.0, webbrowser-control

I have an application which logs into a webpage. But when the user opens the webpage in IE, it opens it without problems. So the user can logout/change username in IE and that will affect my app. Can I make only my webbrowser control to be logged?

Answer (score 0):

Have the encapsulating program add a header to each request.  On the server side you can reject any requests that do not present the header.